# Prevent underlying div from scrolling

Tags: html, css

If there way to make fixed element scroll and prevent parent div from scrolling

Html

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="fixed">
   Long content
  </div>
</div>
```

Css

```css
.container {
  height: 2000px;
  background: green;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  z-index: 20;
  background:#EABFCB;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9t56vce4/6/)

I'm really looking forward to css only solution

Comment: if the child is position:fixed .. why not have it outside of that DOM nesting? and why not have .container{ overflow: hidden }?

Comment: Because it is react App and the container is main `div` where routes is mounted.

Answer (score 0):

Use another `<div>` inside `.fixed`, and also limit its height.

```css
.container {
  height: 2000px;
  background: green;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 20;
  background:#EABFCB;
}

.fixed div {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="fixed">
   <div>
     Long content
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! Yes I thought about this, but I don't really like idea of making one more nesting only to make styles work. I was hoping for css solution only

Comment: I see. It would have been better if you had made it clear in the question.

Answer (score 0):

settting .container is flow, you can make container position is fixed.

Comment: Cannot catch what you are saying. You can edit jsfiddle

Comment: It would be helpful if you could also add the corrected code to your answer.